# Styling is not applied on Kendo grid and Chart in Angular2

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2

I have loaded all the dependencies that are required for kendo grid and chart. I have even checked the node_modules/@progress folder. The grid and chart are loaded but the styling is missing.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the KendoUI default theme, which is not a dependancy to other kendo packages.

```
@progress/kendo-theme-default
```

See documentation and tutorial here :
http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/styling/

You can then include the all.css file in your  tag, or include it in your root component (usually app.component) with Encapsuation set to None, so it can be applied to all components beneath.

If you want to use the scss file, you need to configure your package manager to be able to build scss files.

Comment: Thanks. I actually did that. I gave a reference in my component like below. Are there any other steps to be followed but it didn't work.   styleUrls: ['../../node_modules/@progress/kendo-theme-default/dist/all.css']

Comment: If you put this in your component you need to do other steps because of style encapsulation. See my other answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41856955/kendo-angular-2-themes/41869272#41869272

Comment: I tried the way you suggested. But when I build my webpack its failing. It is unable to read -@import "~@progress/kendo-theme-default/scss/all"; Is there any simple way to make the kendo theme work for my kendo grid. When I tried to include only in my component, style ViewEncapsulation is not recognized. Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: Because you probably miss the sass loader for scss files. Simplest way is probably to include directly the dist/all.css in your <head> tag

Comment: It works. Thanks. But can you suggest why the actual way is failing ?

Comment: You probably have a mistake in your webpack configuration relative to loading scss files.